# Is saying something like "I know how to do that" or "I can't do that because I don't know how" considered objective or subjective?

Tags: objectivity, subjectivity

I want to say these are subjective because don't they refer to a person's personal knowledge about something while still either being true or false? Or would they be considered objective?

Comment: Is knowing action sequences and their likely consequences different in terms of subjective/objective than knowing sensations/perceptions and their classifications? For example, one might proclaim *"I know what red looks like"* or *"I know chocolate when I taste it".* These statements are not asserting the classification of any particular object or substance, but broadcasting the presence of certain familiarity. Actions may relate to familiarity with *system output,* but perceptions relate to familiarity with *system input.*

Comment: What about a statement such as "there sure seem to be a lot of [Joe Millers](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/43326/43326-h/43326-h.htm) being told lately?" Is that an objective statement?

Answer (score 1):

In Western antiquity, the distinction between knowing-that (which might be seen as tending towards objectivity) and knowing-how was spoken of as the [*epistêmê*/*technê* distinction](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/episteme-techne/):

> ... even Aristotle refers to *technê* or craft as itself also *epistêmê* or knowledge because it is a practice grounded in an ‘account’ — something involving theoretical understanding. Plato — whose theory of forms seems an arch example of pure theoretical knowledge — nevertheless is fascinated by the idea of a kind of *technê* that is informed by knowledge of forms. In the *Republic* this knowledge is the indispensable basis for the philosophers’ craft of ruling in the city. Picking up another theme in Plato’s dialogues, the Stoics develop the idea that virtue is a kind of *technê* or craft of life, one that is based on an understanding of the universe. The relation, then, between *epistêmê* and *technê* in ancient philosophy offers an interesting contrast with our own notions about theory (pure knowledge) and (experience-based) practice. There is an intimate positive relationship between *epistêmê* and *technê*, as well as a fundamental contrast.

Much (much) later, Gilbert Ryle [argued against a reduction of know-how to knowledge-that](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/knowledge-how/), which arguments led to modern debates between intellectualists and anti-intellectualists; the former might be thought of as prioritizing the objective component of know-how (such as it is), whereas the latter prioritize something internal and so perhaps construed as primarily subjective. But so one might say that there is no exclusivity in play: an intellectualist can emphasize know-how as primarily objective but secondarily subjective, and *vice versa* for the anti-intellectualist. Or either stance can be internalized to distinctions within subjectivity itself (which itself is not necessarily separate from objective realms; c.f. the concept of [intersubjectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersubjectivity)).